# Как избежать накопление неиспользуемого CSS-кода в ходе жизни сайта?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как избежать накопление неиспользуемого CSS-кода в ходе жизни и развития сайта?
Имеется изначальная версия веб-сайта. По ходу его развития, A/B тестирования, экспериментов с блоками/трансформации внешнего вида блоков столкнулся с такой проблемой, что хочешь-не хочешь, но постепенно остаются рудименты в CSS-стилях от предыдущих подверсий сайта. Более того, некоторые классы встречаются несколько раз: ПК-версия, планшет, смартфон. Прошу советов и рекомендаций, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Не знаю, как вы это все делаете, но лично я старые стили сворачиваю в комментарии. А комментарии возле которых нет записок типа `!experiment`, `!fix`, `!warning` удаляю в следующих несколько версиях. И не думаю что у меня есть неиспользуемые css стили.

Comment: Ещё разделяю стили на 3 группы - `Main`, `Global`, `Local`. `Main` это стили, которые применяются ко всем элементам типа `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; outline: none; box-sizing: border-box; }`. `Global` это стили, которые в основном "общие". То есть если взять `Global` стили и перенести на другой проект то они создадут некий, не конфликтующий дизайн типа `kbd { margin: 0.25vmin 0.5vmin; padding: 0.5vmin 1vmin; border-radius: 4px; }`. А `Local` это стили для конкретно этого проекта и при переносе css файла в другой проект я сразу удаляю все `Local` стили. Так у меня остается только то что нужно.

Comment: [Пример](https://github.com/eccs0103/Cheatsheet/blob/main/styles/themes/material.dark.css) - как работает эта система.